# Can a miner's hashrate be derived from shares submitted at a given difficulty?

Tags: mining-pools, difficulty, mining-pool-shares

Trying to generate useful stats about client activity in a pool. If a quantity of submitted (timestamped) shares is known, and the difficulty of each share is known, how can the client's aggregate hashrate be determined?

Answer (score 2):

```
hashes = shares * share_difficulty * 2**48 / 65535
```

thus:

```
megahash_per_second = shares_per_second * share_difficulty * 4295.032833
```

Comment: Conceptually: Compute the expected number of hashes required to find each share that is actually found and sum them. Divide by the amount of time to get the hash rate.